# How to design the application list in the iphone tip application

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-column

[image]

How to design the application list in the picture? Use ListView or Column?

Comment: I think it is using CustomScrollView, Can you include what you've done far?

Answer (score 0):

You can create the layout like this.

```
Column(
 children:[
   BannerSectionHere(),
   ...List.generate(3, (index){
     return Row(
      children: [
       Container(child:Image.network()),
       Column(
        children: [
          Text("Title text here"),
          Text("SubTitle text here"),
        ]
       )
      ]
    );
   }
 ]
)
```